# Angular 2/4/5 (Not AngularJS) :- how can I take .offset().top of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

How can I take value of offset top in Angular? In jQuery we had

```
var topVal = $("p").offset().top
```

How can I get the value of `topVal` variable using Angular?

Comment: You don't need a framework or library for that, use [HTMLElement.offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in a comment, you don't need a framework for such a simple DOM introspection. You can simply leverage [offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop). Observe the following...

```
<p>hello</p>
```

---

```
p {
  margin: 1.000em;
}
```

---

```
let p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
console.log(p.offsetTop); // 16
```

[example vanilla jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hLfb048e/)

If you absolutely insist this must be done with angular, well, angular simply leverages jqLite via [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

> jqLite is a tiny, API-compatible subset of jQuery that allows
>   AngularJS to manipulate the DOM in a cross-browser compatible way.
>   jqLite implements only the most commonly needed functionality with the
>   goal of having a very small footprint.

...which, does not have an `.offset()` implementation so you are only left with the first suggestion.

---

Edit, it's come to my attention that this is regarding angular 2.x and up. The answer stands regardless - you're wanting a DOM element property... use the DOM API.

Comment: Angular2/4/6 not with AngularJS

Comment: @SáähilKumar Doesn't matter much. If anything, you'd then be forced to use the native DOM property even more. Aside from the history lesson, this is the answer regardless